# Git Server Side Hooks not running?

Tags: git, githooks

I'm new to Server Side Hooks with Git, and I'm running into a problem where it seems like the hooks just aren't running at all. My Git repo is a bare repo.

All I want to do is extract one file from the repo and write it to disk somewhere else. I don't need the entire archive.

On the remote (origin) server, I have authored this file and stuck it in `/my/path/repo.git/hooks`.

```
#!/bin/sh

# For debugging
echo "HELLO" > /my/path/hello.txt

# Auto-deploy thefile.php to /my/path/ every time something is pushed to this repo
exec git -C /my/path/repo.git show master:thefile.php > /my/path/thefile.php
```

I have verified the permissions on the hook:

> -rwxrwxr-x 1 webadmin webadmin  543 Jan 15 16:27 post-update

If I manually run the script on my server, with `$ ./path/to/repo.git/hooks/post-update`, everything works fine. `hello.txt` is written along with `thefile.php`.

But when I push my local repo to origin nothing ever changes. I am testing my pushes by reverting the latest commit and pushing it. For the next test, I drop that revert commit and force push to remove it from `origin/master`. That way are there are actual commits with changes that are going every time I push. Out of desperation I did make a completely new commit with an arbitrary change, and that didn't make any difference.

I've tried this hook as both `post-update` and `post-receive`. Neither one seems to work.

I would greatly appreciate any insight you guys can provide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you are pushing to the bare repo you think you are: in that bare repo, on the server, do a `git status` and a `git log`, to confirm that the commits you are pushing are indeed there.

Second, check the log of the listener which allows you to push to that bare repo: SSH or HTTPS.
If you don't have an HTTP(S) listener, consider adding one for testing: the easiest would be gitea ([just one executable](https://gitea.io/en-us/))

Third, check the version of Git on the server, in case it is somehow too old.

The [OP DOOManiac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/192831/doomaniac) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59760619/git-server-side-hooks-not-running/59763567?noredirect=1#comment105728496_59763567)

> The 2nd part gave me a clue that led me to the real answer:
>
> I was pushing via filesystem share (mapped network drive in Windows) and apparently those don't trigger hooks on the server as there is no listener.
>
> Changed everything to use SSH and now its working. Thanks!
> (On a side note, this also explains why my "`git config noff`" policy was being ignored.)

Comment: The 2nd part gave me a clue that led me to the real answer: I was pushing via filesystem share (mapped network drive in Windows) and apparently those don't trigger hooks on the server as there is no listener.

Changed everything to use SSH and now its working. Thanks!

(On a side note, this also explains why my "git config noff" policy was being ignored.)

Comment: @DOOManiac Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I made things work on my side after running with the same problems.
Here is the script I used:

```
#!/bin/sh
unset GIT_DIR
cd /volume1/{path to your repository}
git fetch origin master
git reset --hard FETCH_HEAD
echo "post-receive hook executed on $(date)" >> /volume1/{path to your repository}/post-receive.log
```

Then I updated at least for one commit the access rights to the user accessing Git Server on the synology (Files with access read/write), and when it worked I revoked the access rights and it is still working.